# Change of Status in Dynamics CRM 2016 8.1

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I have written code that is supposed to help us automate some specific cases. It will create a addresstag for the customer and change the status of the case to "Address Tag Sent".
All this works as intended, but for some reason the status of the case is changed back to "New".

As you can see [**here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJwWX.png) there is an event called "Activate" that changes the status.
I haven't found what this event is or why it occurs. I have gone through all the Workflows we got, all processes, all code (As good as I can) and spent a good amount of time trying to google it but I still come out empty handed.

Is there someone who might know what this event is? Or maybe got any idea how to access/modify it?

Comment: Any followup questions?

Answer (score 0):

'Activate' will essentially re-activate any record and put the statuscode back to the default statuscode\status reason - I am guessing your default is set to 'New'.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would investigate in these directions:

1. Since “changed by” showing as “CRM migration account”, this maybe an ETL job like SSIS, or Scribe which is syncing data changes from outside integration
2. Maybe the same service account is used by plugin, to reset the StateCode and StatusCode on some business logic
3. Is there some Business process flow stages available in your form, as I see “Service stage” attribute in audit before that, there may be logics coupled with that

Verify the dependencies of statecode attribute in customizations to see any SDK steps or workflows referencing that. Check in your code repos and check with any long timers in your project for any business logics implemented in the past.